# ajax return 0 and cut

Tags: ajax, callback

there,
I have php action_events_work_time that answer:

---

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [html] =>   Мои трудозатраты ч.ч (433.12 | 0 | 122.51)Общие затраты ч.ч (1030.12 | 5362)
)
```

---

I have ajax request:

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/project/event/events_work_time',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        //var data = resp.upload;

        if(resp.error == false){
            $('#events_work_time').html(resp.html);

        }else{
            $('#events_work_time').html('Ошибка при загрузке');
        }

    }
});
```

---

But ajax answer is only

---

`Мои трудозатраты ч.ч (433.12 | 0 | 0)` <---This var is **0**???

---

The last variable is 0. Why??? Can someone solve this?? I use kohana framework + twig

Comment: Are sending response with `echo json_encode($array); exit;` ?

Comment: Yes, I used json_encode(),json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),json_encode($c, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), at the end result the same: (433.12 | 0 | 0), and it cut the other part of php result

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all that wanted to help. I solved it by myself. The problem was that ajax did not sent some data to php. Just added data parameter to ajax. And changed

`$this->cur_project['id']` to `$_POST['project_id'];` in php

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/project/event/events_work_time',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: {'project_id': "{{event}}"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        //var data = resp.upload;

        if(resp.error == false){
            $('#events_work_time').html(resp.html);
        }else{
            $('#events_work_time').html('Ошибка при загрузке');
        }

    }
});
```